# How to clear the pasteboard / find string from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, copy-paste

I want to be able clear out the whatever data is cached in find (command-f) clipboard contents from the command line.

Whatever is in there seems to carry across between applications. This is a clear security risk in some cases.

- [How to secure macOS's clipboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281394/how-to-secure-macoss-clipboard)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How so a security risk?  Surely you don't have more than one person using the same user account?

Answer (score 8):

The magic words seem to be

```
pbcopy -pboard find < /dev/null
```