# Can iOS apps read your clipboard, and can it be stopped?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, security, copy-paste

An [article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/06/tiktok-and-53-other-ios-apps-still-snoop-your-sensitive-clipboard-data/) says that iOS apps have been caught reading data from user's clipboards:

> researchers found the following iOS apps were reading users’ clipboard data every time the app was opened with no clear reason for doing so:
>
> - ABC News — com.abcnews.ABCNews
> - Al Jazeera English — ajenglishiphone
> - CBC News — ca.cbc.CBCNews
> - CBS News — com.H443NM7F8H.CBSNews
> - CNBC — com.nbcuni.cnbc.cnbcrtipad
> - Fox News — com.foxnews.foxnews

(51 more apps not shown for brevity)

#### Question

Are all iOS apps able to read the iPhone clipboard, and if so, how can I get a list of which apps are doing it, and be notified each time they do it?

#### Also note

By extension, macOS's ['handoff'](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl732d3c0a/mac) feature allows apple devices share clipboards when within 10 feet of each other. So in addition to being able to read the *iPhone*'s clipboard, are these iOS apps also able to read the user's *MacBook's* clipboard (whenever it's within 10 feet, as demonstrated in the youtube link below)?

- [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tegfZNv8SBc) demonstrates how an iOS app with access to the clipboard can read not only the clipboard on the iPhone/iPad, but also on any MacBook or Mac within 10 feet (via 'handoff', which is 'On' by default on macOS devices).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to secure macOS's clipboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281394/how-to-secure-macoss-clipboard)

Comment: @Tetsujin I hadn't come across that question/answer before posting this, but it was extremely interesting, albeit almost four years old (and a touch speculative). But most importantly, it's asking about macOS - this question is asking about iOS.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was sure we had a similar one for iOS, can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: @stevec There is an interesting related thread here: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2020/06/iphone_apps_ste.html

Answer (score 2):

Any iOS can always access the clipboard, there isn't really a way to prevent this from happening. Recent iOS versions show a little info box at the top of the screen when this happens so you should be at least aware if an app does this "in the background".

PS: An app can *not* access clipboards on other devices. What happens with Handoff is that the clipboards are synced across devices by the OSes (macOS and iOS) *in the background* so that at the moment an app access the clipboard it may get the content you just copied into it a few seconds ago on your Mac.